# How to Generate a Widget Script?

Tags: javascript, widget

Do you know of any tutorials or walkthroughs, or something to read, on how to make a widget script generator? Not even sure that term is correct.

I have a web app idea, and part of it I basically want to read in info, settings, whatever and generate a script based on that. Which could either be copy/pasted into a site, or hotlinked, not sure yet. But I have no idea about how to do the generation.

The twitter follow button creator is a good example of what I am trying to do, it pulls in a base script no matter what, (I think) and it uses data- attributes in the 'a' tag to communicate changes?

Would love any input, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a [Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=widget+wizard)

[Creating a javascript widget for other sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411501/creating-a-javascript-widget-for-other-sites)

[How to embed Javascript widget that depends on jQuery into an unknown environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170439/how-to-embed-javascript-widget-that-depends-on-jquery-into-an-unknown-environment)